# No visible @interface for 'RCTBundleURLProvider' declares the selector 'jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:'

Tags: ios, react-native, appdelegate

This is the error that i am getting when building the app.

I am getting this error after upgrading my react-native version from `0.66.2` to `0.68.2` in my `Appdelegate.mm` file.

[image]

Answer (score 200, accepted):

After some research i found out that `jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:` no longer exists on `RCTBundleURLProvider`.

**Here's the Fix:**

**Replace**

```
return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

**with**

```
return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
```

Re-Build the app and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks very much, same upgrade journey as you! (66 to 69)

Comment: Fixed my error that was: The following build commands failed:
 CompileC /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...-cnhglescntkhmbendriezncnfrun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/...build/Debug-iphonesimulator/....build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o /Users/.../repos/.../ios/.../AppDelegate.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Comment: Adding this note for other encountering a similar issue after using this fix then upgrading to the macOS Monterey 12.6.1 -> 

I had been using this patch (and it worked great!) but was causing the same error after the latest update.   Reverting it fixed the issue.

Comment: Tried this but then it just says: ```Can't find the 'node' binary to build the React Native bundle.  If you have a non-standard Node.js installation, select your project in Xcode, find  'Build Phases' - 'Bundle React Native code and images' and change NODE_BINARY to an  absolute path to your node executable. You can find it by invoking 'which node' in the terminal.```

Comment: Thanks so much! The same issue occurred to me by upgrading from Expo SDK 44 to 45.